# Adding class to form select parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a form where only 2 checkboxes can be selected at any one time. I also need it so the container li of these checkboxes have a different background once selected. I have done this.

I'm unable to work out how to stop the class being added to the li when the user tries to select a 3rd checkbox. The jQuery stops the 3rd checkbox from being selected (which is correct); but I need the outer li to not have the class added to it.

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried hasClass, and doing if statements in the length>2 but I cannot quite grasp it.

https://jsfiddle.net/61hof9n0/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="" id="new_compare-form">
  <li class="main-table">
    <span class="ctas">
          <span class="cta cta-compare">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxcompare" name="compare-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="compare">Compare</label>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="main-table">
    <span class="ctas">
          <span class="cta cta-compare">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxcompare" name="compare-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="compare">Compare</label>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="main-table">
    <span class="ctas">
          <span class="cta cta-compare">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxcompare" name="compare-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="compare">Compare</label>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input.checkboxcompare').change(function(e){
       if ($('input.checkboxcompare:checked').length > 2) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
       }
    })

    $('#new_compare-form :checkbox').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('red');
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: check new update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/61hof9n0/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input.checkboxcompare').change(function(e){
    if ($('input.checkboxcompare:checked').length > 2) {
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
          $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('red');
    }
 })
 
 $('#new_compare-form :checkbox').on('click', function(){
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('red');
 });
```

```css
.red {
  color:red;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="" id="new_compare-form">
  <li class="main-table">
    <span class="ctas">
    <span class="cta cta-compare">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxcompare" name="compare-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="compare">Compare</label>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="main-table">
    <span class="ctas">
    <span class="cta cta-compare">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxcompare" name="compare-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="compare">Compare</label>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="main-table">
    <span class="ctas">
    <span class="cta cta-compare">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxcompare" name="compare-<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" value="compare">Compare</label>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Ranjeet, when I select a 3rd, the class is removed. I need to keep the class without it being removed if a 3rd is selected. Do you know what I need to do? https://jsfiddle.net/61hof9n0/2/